# Exportação de dados CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pessoal alguém teria algum exemplo de como criar uma exportação de dados via web em .CSV? eu já tenho uma em meu sistema em .XLS, porém preciso modifica-la, alguem pode ajudar?

**Controller**

```
private void ExportacaoDados(DataSet data, string fileName, int type = 0)
        {
            if (type == 0)
            {
                var gv = new GridView();
                gv.DataSource = data;
                gv.DataBind();

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xls");
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.Charset = "";
                var sw = new StringWriter();
                var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                gv.RenderControl(htw);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());

                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();
                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                var sw = new StringWriter();
                sw.Write(ExportToCSVFile(data.Tables[0]));

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".txt");
                Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                Response.Charset = "";
                var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());

                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();
                Response.End();
            }
        }

        private string ExportToCSVFile(DataTable dtTable)
        {
            var sbldr = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (DataColumn c in dtTable.Columns)
            {
                sbldr.Append(Regex.Replace(c.ColumnName, @"\n|\t|\r", "") + "|");
            }

            sbldr.Append("\r\n");
            foreach (DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dtTable.Columns)
                {
                    sbldr.Append(Regex.Replace(row[column].ToString(), @"\n|\t|\r", "") + "|");
                }
                sbldr.AppendLine();
            }

            return sbldr.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: csv, é arquivo de texto... só escrever... qual a origem dos dados ?

Comment: Eu fiz uma query puxando dos dados no meu SQL Server nisso trago a exportação

Comment: Coloque o código que já fez

Comment: Da uma olhada [nessa biblioteca](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), ela é capaz de serializar uma classe ou converter valores para CSV.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Atualizei o topico

Comment: @gato vou dar uma olhada!

Answer (score 1):

Esse seu código, acredito que esteja correto, só acho desnecessário o Replace no nome da coluna, e, utilizar `,` ou `;` para separar os campos, não o pipe `|` mas, ok.

```
    private string ExportToCSVFile(DataTable dtTable)
    {
        var sbldr = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DataColumn c in dtTable.Columns)
        {
            sbldr.Append(c.ColumnName+ ";");
        }

        sbldr.Append("\r\n");
        foreach (DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dtTable.Columns)
            {
                sbldr.Append(Regex.Replace(row[column].ToString(), @"\n|\t|\r", "") + ";");
            }
            sbldr.AppendLine();
        }

        return sbldr.ToString();
    }
```

Se quiser continuar com ele, e depois escrever o retorno em um arquivo texto:

```
string csv = ExportToCSVFile(dtTable);
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(arquivo, false, Encoding.Default))
{
   tw.Write(csv);
   tw.Close();
}
```

onde: `arquivo` é uma string com o caminho do arquivo que você irá salvar, e depois disponibilizar para download.

> Dependendo do tamanho do conteúdo, acredito que será mais rápido se abrir o Writer dentro do método que gera o csv e ir escrevendo no arquivo ao invés de guardar em uma string.
>
> Se possível, utilize a biblioteca pronta pra isso, certamente o resultado será melhor, evitaria a perda das quebras de linha, tabulação e caracteres de escape dentro de strings.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro conselho que te dou, tente adaptar o seu código para que ele receba uma lista tipada no lugar de um DataTable. Porem o exemplo abaixo vai levar em contar que continuara com o DataTable.

Outro ponto, escrever um arquivo CSV envolve dezenas de pequenos detalhes, então faze-lo manualmente, tornará o seu codigo bastante propenso à erros, então aconselho que utilize o [`CsvHelper`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/).

```
private void ExportacaoDados(DataSet data, string fileName, int type = 0)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".txt");
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    ExportToCSVFile(Response.OutputStream, data.Tables[0]);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
    Response.End();
}

private void ExportToCSVFile(Stream stream, DataTable table)
{
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-15");
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, encoding, 1024, true))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            foreach (var column in table.Columns)
            {
                csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
            }
            csv.NextRecord();
            foreach (var row in table.Rows)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(row[i]);
                }
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acabei de adicionar o CsvHelper, só que na linha csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName); em ColumnName Está dando erro   'object' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnName' and no extension method 'ColumnName' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: e na linha csv.WriteField(row[i]); em row[i] Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: Este seu DataTable é o que é definido em System.Data?

Comment: Mandou bem no ISO-8859-15... geralmente rodando o sistema em ambiente de lingua inglesa, sendo os dados em portuga, dá um monte de problemas +1 por isso!